# I have just the Started the learning the Type Script ans getting the below error.please help on this and what could be the mistake?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

```
var n:string = "mary";
```

`D:\Angular\TS>node Untitled_2.ts`

```
D:\Angular\TS\Untitled_2.ts:1(function (exports, require, module, 
__filename, __dirname) { var n:string = "mary";
                                                               ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code that causes the error. I guess you need to move the code inside a function.

Comment: your code snippet is incomprehensible

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have to compile Typescript code before you can run it with node. You can do this two ways.

1. Run `tsc Untitled_2.ts` and then run `node Untitled_2.js` (assuming no extra config that changes output paths)
2. Install [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) and run `ts-node Untitled_2.ts`

You may need to prefix the above commands with `npm run` or `yarn` to add the command to your path.